# Edit button not displayed in UITabBarController's MoreNavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller

A `UITabBarController` is being pushed onto the stack:

```
let presenter = presentingViewController as! UINavigationController
let tabvc = UITabBarController()
tabvc.viewControllers = vcs
tabvc.customizableViewControllers = vcs
presenter.pushViewController(tabvc, animated: true)
```

Once presented the more tab button correctly shows, but the edit button to rearrange the tab bars does not. According to the [docs on the MoreNavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW8):

> The interface for the standard More item includes an Edit button that
>   allows the user to reconfigure the tab bar. By default, the user is
>   allowed to rearrange all items on the tab bar. If you do not want the
>   user to modify some items, though, you can remove the appropriate view
>   controllers from the array in the customizableViewControllers
>   property.

My guess is that the tab bar is not happy being in a navigation controller. Any ideas on bringing the edit button back?

Comment: Any reason you need to use a navigation controller to hold your tab bar controller? As you have noted, I think this could well be you issue. Better would be to present the tab bar controller modally using `presentViewController` which is supported according to the docs.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel: Answering for **memmons**, it is a common situation with applications which require, say, a *login* or an *onboarding*. You start out with a navigation controller, and later on must somehow  transition to a tab bar controller.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I get the use case, but you can implement that a number of ways which fit better with how container controllers like to work. Hence my comment on whether it really has to be pushed from a nav controller, given presenting it modally would likely solve the issue. As described very well in your answer 8^).

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel: in full agreement. `Push` is, out of all options, the one that shall not be used. It causes a double-navigation conundrum, with both a back button and bottom tabs, all craving attention. Thank you for clarifying ; I can remove my comment if you with, since it does not add to the question, and I clearly misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect is absolutely correct about why this approach is sometimes needed. In my case the login controller as well as the next vc pushed onto the stack doesn't require a tab bar controller. Pushing the next stack of vcs with a modal tab bar controller _could_ be an option, but as soon as you do that you are significantly increasing your memory footprint as well as sacrificing some flexibility in design. In theory, a tab bar controller should just be a wrapper that plays nice -- even if itself is contained in a nav controller.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can have both a `UINavigationController` and a `UITabBarController` ; using `Storyboard` helps understand the issue better, any of these solutions will work:

1. Start out with a `UITabBarController` as *initial view controller*
2. Use `presentViewController` instead of `pushViewController`
3. Use a modal `Storyboard` segue to perform a modal presentation
4. Swap out the `rootViewController` dynamically

---

## Initial View Controller Design

When the Tab Bar Controller *is initial View Controller*, the **Edit** button is displayed normally.

[image]

---

## Pushed Design

Another Navigation Controller **is** *initial View Controller*, using one of 5 *adaptive* Action Segue:

- Show
- Custom

-> No **Edit** button, since it is in direct conflict with the parent `UITableViewController`.

- Show Detail
- Present Modally
- Popover Presentation

-> **Edit** button displayed as expected.

[image]

---

## Code

**1. Program Modal**

Using the exact code presented in the question, change the last line:

```
let presenter = presentingViewController as! UINavigationController
let tabvc = UITabBarController()
tabvc.viewControllers = vcs
tabvc.customizableViewControllers = vcs
presenter.presentViewController(tabvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**2. Storyboard Modal**

keeping with the `Storyboard` theme, create a segue of the correct type, assign an identifier (i.e. *presentModallySegue*) and the 5 lines above become this **single line**:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("presentModallySegue", sender: self)
```

**3. root Swap**

A more drastic solution involves swapping out the root view controller at the `window` level:

```
let tabvc = UITabBarController()
tabvc.viewControllers = vcs
tabvc.customizableViewControllers = vcs
self.view.window!.rootViewController = tabvc
```

---

## Conclusion

Either change your design to adopt the Tab Bar Controller as the *initial View Controller*, or present the Tab Bar Controller **modally**.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that navigation bar of your presenter overlaps with the navigation bar of **More** section.

If you **don't show** the navigation bar for you navigation controller, you will be able to see the **Edit** button again when you tap on the **More** tab.