# Pushing a TabBarController inside a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I am trying to push an `TabBarController` inside an UINavigationController however as soon as I push the very first controller that display has no navigation bar, as soon as I use the tab bar buttons to navigate on the other screens it shows up, I try to add it manually on the landing page for the tab bar as below:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "upload"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("cameraTap"))
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = barItem
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "welcome to the jungle"
```

This is how I am calling the TabBarController

```
func startApp(){
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let overviewVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    overviewVC.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    if logInController != nil{
        logInController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    overviewVC.selectedIndex = 0
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(overviewVC, animated: true)
}
```

I also try to assigned it to `self.navigationController.tabBarController` but it seems to be readonly so far no luck.

View organization:

```
Nav Contr -> View Contr -> Tab Contr -> View Contr 1
                                     -> View Contr 2
                                     -> View Contr 3
```

Comment: are the viewcontorllers in your tabBAr rooted in their own UINavigationControllers? meaning that each tab has it's own UINavigationController?

Comment: @Larcerax I add the view organization in the question, sorry I miss that important detail before

Comment: perfect, I think I may knwo what's wrong but I won't be albe to post for about an hour or so, if someone beats me to it great, if not, I'll post asap

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767022/edit-button-not-displayed-in-uitabbarcontrollers-morenavigationcontroller?noredirect=1#comment52296869_31767022 which has a detailed description and a sample project.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect thanks but still the same, always the land page does not present the navBar as soon as I click in any tab it start to display